# Admob on my Custom SurfaceView

Tags: android, admob, android-relativelayout, surfaceview

I have created a my custom `SurfaceView` and now want to place admob on surface view. Not below or above because it reduces the screen size. I found many questions here but all are solving by putting `SurfaceView` below or above of the admob view. but I want to put admob on `SurfaceView`.

XML code of my Activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SecondActivity" >

<com.scratchview.ScratchView
    xmlns:wsv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scratch_view_background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    wsv:antiAlias="true"
    wsv:revealSize="25dp"
    wsv:scratchable="false" />

<com.scratchview.ScratchView
    xmlns:wsv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scratch_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    wsv:antiAlias="true"
    wsv:revealSize="25dp"
    wsv:scratchable="true" />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="top"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note: I have tried by putting Admob below and above it is working fine. I need to put admob onto `SurfaceView`

Comment: first u make different layout for admob and then include the layout where u want to take it

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you put Admob on the SurfaceView you will also be reducing the screen available to your game/app.